# Is a directory @ rb_sysopen というエラー文が出る　Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, 画像

Progateのrailsのコースを見ながらアプリを作っています。今プロフィール画像をアップロードしたくてつまづいております。コードはProgateのものをそのまま持ってきてるのですがどうもうまくいきません。
エラー文も今までに見たことないもので調べてもよくわからないです。ここだけで半日以上止まってしまっています。
やりたいことは

画像をpublic/user_imagesに保存
保存された画像をプロフィールページに表示する（ユーザーごとに画像は変更できる）
です。

どうかご教授くださいませ。

home_controller.rb

```
   def update_user
    　@user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    　@user.name = params[:name]
    　@user.email = params[:email]
    　if params[:image]
     　 @user.image_name = "#{@user.id}.jpg"
     　 image = params[:image]
     　 File.binwrite("public/user_images/#{@user.image_name}",image.read)
   　 end
   　 if @user.save
      　flash[:notice] = "ユーザー情報を編集しました"
      　redirect_to("/")
    　end
　　end

　　def profile
  　  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  　  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
  　  @likes = Like.where(user_id: @user.id)
　　end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get "home/test" => "home#barbajs"


  get ":id/edit_profile" => "home#edit_profile"
  get "account/:id/edit" => "home#edit_account"
  post "user/:id/update" => "home#update_user"
  get 'pay/payment'
  devise_for :users
  get "home/:id/likes" => "home#likes"
  post "likes/:post_id/create" => "likes#create"
  post "likes/:post_id/destroy" => "likes#destroy"

  root 'home#index'
  get "home/new_fc" => "home#new_fc"
  post "home/create" => "home#create"
  get "home/profile/:id" => "home#profile"
  get ":id/show_fc" => "home#show_fc"
  get ":id/edit_fc" => "home#edit_fc"
  post ":id/update_fc" => "home#update_fc"
  post ":id/fc/destroy" => "home#destroy"
  get ":id/setting" => "home#setting"
  get "pay" => "pay#payment"
  get "home/new_fc_content" => "home#new_fc_content"
  post "home/content_create" => "home#content_create"
end
```

edit_profile.html.erb(プロフィール編集ページ)

```
<h3>プロフィール編集</h3>

<%= form_tag("/user/#{current_user.id}/update", {multipart: true}) do %>
  <p>ユーザー名</p>
  <textarea name="name" class="textbox"><%= current_user.name %></textarea>
  <li>自己紹介変更</li>
  <li>プロフィール写真変更</li>
  <p>画像</p>
  <input name="image" type="file">
  <input type="submit" value="これで完成！" class="btn btn-light-green btn-size-large">
<% end %>
```

profile.html.erb(プロフィールページ)

```
<div class="main">
<h2><%= @user.name %></h2>
<img src="<%= "/user_images/#{@user.image_name}" %>">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ファンクラブ総会員数</th>
    <th>入会ファンクラブ数</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: エラー文]

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/143545

Answer (score 1):

`Is a directory` は、ファイルを open しようとしたが、それはディレクトリだった、というエラーです。

直接的な原因は、スクリーンショットにあるとおり、open しようとしたファイル名が `public/user_images/` になっていることです。
つまり、

```
 File.binwrite("public/user_images/#{@user.image_name}",image.read)
```

この部分で、`@user.image_name` が `""` か `nil` か、そんなところだと思います。

User クラスのコードが質問文にないのでこれ以上はわかりませんが、
User クラスの `image_name` メソッドや `image_name=` メソッドが自分で作成したメソッドならば、これらのコードを再確認してみてはいかがでしょう?